# How to display the time of a Date object based on DateFormat.SHORT and locale?

Tags: java, date, java-7

I am using Java 7 and I need to display the time part of a Java `Date` object.

I notice that `DateFormat` has the `SHORT` constant according to [the page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and the page has the following description:

> `SHORT` is completely numeric, such as 12.13.52 or 3:30pm

My question is how to display only the time part (such as "3:30pm"). The following is what I have and it only shows the date part (such as 2/14/15):

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, A_Locale_object);
SimpleDateFormat sf = (SimpleDateFormat) f;
sf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to display is the time part, what ou need to call is `getTimeInstance()`, and not `getDateInstance()`.

This is the kind of answer that you should learn to find by yourself, simply by reading [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

> Use getDateInstance to get the normal date format for that country. There are other static factory methods available. Use getTimeInstance to get the time format for that country. Use getDateTimeInstance to get a date and time format.

Answer (score 1):

So If you want to display the time part, what you can do is provide the format to SimpleDatFormat and your locale like below
`SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", your_locale);` 
And format it like you did
`sd.format(new Date()));` 
If you want more stuff to be formatted, you can definitely add more like `"YY.MM.dd hh:mm a"`
You can read the SimpleDateFormat document for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `getTimeInstance`  instead of `getDateInstance`.

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Time Zone

The Question and other Answers neglect the crucial issue of time zone. If not specified, the JVM’s current default time zone is automatically applied.

## Joda-Time

Such work is easier with the Joda-Time library.

Example using Joda-Time 2.7.

Translate the java.util.Date object to a Joda-Time `DateTime` object. Unlike a `Date`, a `DateTime` understands its assigned time zone. We want to adjust from the `Date` object’s [UTC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) zone to a desired zone such as Montréal.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( yourDate, zone ) ;
```

Generate a String representation of this date-time value. A pair of characters passed to `forStyle` control the full, long, short etc. format of the date portion and the time portion. A hyphen suppresses display of that portion.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "-S" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = formatter.print( dateTime ) ;
```